# Install ruby devkit on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows

I'm trying install devkit to instal some gems. I downloaded files and extracted properly and run ruby dk.rb init and file config.yml was created right.
When i run ruby dk.rb install i got this:

```
[INFO] Skipping existing gem override for 'C:/Ruby200-x64'
[WARN] Skipping existing DevKit helper library for 'C:/Ruby200-x64'
```

Comment: Are you using the 64-bit devkit?

Comment: this message look like devkit already installed but when i run gem install caldecott ti return an error that i dont have devkit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would delete C:/Ruby200-x64 and re-extract. Then run 64 bit devkit install again. You shouldn't get that error message.

For the record though, I have a working ruby 2.0 on windows 7, and that gem wouldn't build for me either. It installed fine on 1.9.3 though.

In my opinion we're about a year away from seeing 2.0 be usable on windows.

Comment: which one did u installed for 1.9.3??

DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe
DevKit-mingw64-32-4.7.2-20130224-1151-sfx.exe
DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe